Semantic predicate false throws NoViableAltException in adaptivePredict(), then error recovery doesn't rewind _input.p
My grammar is
grammar Interpreter;

conditionalOrExpression : relationalRestriction ( OR relationalRestriction )* ;

relationalRestriction  : primary ( orRestriction )* ;

orRestriction : singleRestriction (OR annotation? singleRestriction)* ;

singleRestriction : operator primary ;

operator : EQUALS
         | {  _input.LT(1).getText().equals("customOperator") }? ID  // check custom operators using java util method
         ;

primary : INT
        | ID
        | '(' ID ')'
        | ID '(' ID ')'
        ;

annotation : AT ID ;

OR     :  '||';
ID     :  [a-zA-Z]+;
INT    :  '0'..'9'+;
EQUALS :  '==';
AT     :  '@';

WS     :  [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

(Sorry that the rules are not intuitive and not simplified well, but it required to reproduce the issue. The whole example is https://github.com/tkobayas/antlr-semantic-predicate-recovery)
Input is a == 5 || notCustomOperator(b) == 6. I expect that notCustomOperator results in false in the semantic predicate in operator rule, so it creates relationalRestriction a == 5 and relationalRestriction notCustomOperator(b) == 6 connected by OR || under conditionalOrExpression.
However, it results in line 1:10 no viable alternative at input 'notCustomOperator' and it doesn't take the alternative I expect above.
I read The prediction process also can't see through token references. Token references have the side effect of advancing the input one symbol. A predicate that tested the current input symbol would find itself out of sync if the parser shifted it over the token reference. in https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md#finding-visible-predicates (and read other similar SO threads), but with a debugger, I actually see that the semantic predicate (operator_sempred()) is executed in ParserATNSimulator.adaptivePredict() in InterpreterParser.orRestriction(). The semantic predicate expectedly returns false and throws NoViableAltException, then it goes to DefaultErrorStrategy.recover(). I expect that it continues to look for alternatives, but a problem is that _input.p is not rewound to ||, so the current token is notCustomOperator, so it cannot match the expected alternative.
That said... probably my expectation was wrong and I have to rewrite the grammar. But I want to confirm if this is a designed behavior (= we cannot rely on semantic predicate for prediction in this case), because the semantic predicate is executed in contradiction to the documentation.

From your grammar it seems that your input is wrong. For input a == 5 || notCustomOperator(b) == 6 there's no path to match the ||. a matched as primary and orRestriction doesn't start with || but wants an operator first. So, ANTLR first tries to match EQUALS which fails for || and then runs the predicate, which also fails. This means there's no viable alt in operator, which in turns fails orRestriction.
I'm not sure if error recovery even tries to find a missing or unwanted token. To me it looks as if that's beyond its abilities. Hence the error.

The grammar could parse the input as intended if (a) orRestriction : singleRestriction (OR annotation? singleRestriction)* ; is rewritten as orRestriction : singleRestriction ;, and (b) remove the semantic predicate from the operator rule. The grammar should be ambiguous, but the diagnostic parser interpreter doesn't report any ambiguity for the input. I don't quite understand why it does not. But likely it is because the OR in the rule--it cannot choose the derivation orRestriction => singleRestriction because it must to expand ('OR' singleRestriction)*.

Thank you for the answer, @Mike Lischke
I expect a == 5 as a relationalRestriction, and notCustomOperator(b) == 6 as a relationalRestriction, then connect the two relationalRestrictions with OR || to compose one conditionalOrExpression. I guess you had understood my expectation, but you wanted to tell that processing orRestriction comes with higher priority, hence results in the error --- antlr4 works like that, right?

Thank you for the answer, @kaby76 .
Thanks, (a) rewritten as orRestriction : singleRestriction ; indeed parses the input as expected (even without doing (b)). However, actually, I want to match || in orRestriction in some occasions (e.g. "a == 5 || == 6). The grammar is ambiguous, but I wanted to discard one alternative by the semantic predicate (= notCustomOperator is not an operator), so result in the expected alternative (match the || as a token in conditionalOrExpression). But I guess your point is that the semantic predicate cannot be used for such a purpose, right?

Thank you for the answers, Mike Lischke and kaby76. Having said, I accept your answers, and probably I'll distill my issue and I will raise another question in a better way. Thanks!

orRestriction : singleRestriction (OR annotation? singleRestriction)*? ; (Adding ? at the end) solved the issue. It may not be a general solution, but it's good for my case.
